# Generating SSH keys for 'apache' user

Tags: php, apache, git, github, ssh-keys

How do I add SSH keys for 'apache' user in Linux?

**BACKGROUND**

I am trying to add a service hook to github to notify a URL once I push to my repo. I have the following php page set up:

```
<?php `git pull origin master`;
```

However I get the following output:

```
sh: git: Permission denied
```

This is because the keys I generated for github access were generated by my 'root' user. However when I exectue a command from php it is the 'apache' user that runs it.

The keys therefore do not correspond and permission is denied to pull.

As I cannot switch user from the terminal to generate keys as 'apache', I am not too sure what to do. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As you are root, you can try it `sudo -u apache ssh-keygen -t rsa`

Comment: Hi. `su -apache` outputs `This account is currently not available.`. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that the user is apache, sometimes its can be `httpd` or `www-data`.

Comment: Yes, I have tested with `echo shell_exec('whoami');` Output is `apache`.

Comment: The `This account is currently not available.`its because your apache user doesn't have shell.

Comment: Give the user `apache` a shell in `/etc/passwd` although I'm not sure about the security implications that my have.

Comment: I finally solved it. I used `sudo -u apache ssh-keygen -t rsa` to generate keys for 'apache'. Thank you.

Answer (score 48):

You may have to copy the root generated keys in the .ssh directory of your apache user.

Assuming the homedir of apache is **/var/www** (check /etc/passwd) and the named key is **id_rsa-git** :

```
mkdir -p /var/www/.ssh/
cp /root/.ssh/id_rsa-git /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa
```

No need to copy the public key.

Note : by default the key used are **id_rsa** or **id_dsa**. You may change the name of the copied key to match this.

You may also change ownership of the **id_rsa** key and **.ssh** directory:

```
chown -R apache:apache /var/www/.ssh
chmod 0700 /var/www/.ssh
chmod 0600 /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's not very safe to do it or is it ?

Comment: It will only tell that the apache user will be able to use a ssh-key. The security is not done at the user-level (where the keys are generated) but at the server level (where the keys are used to authenticate). Nonetheless you have to chown the keys to the apache user... (will update the post)

Comment: @Vincent. Thanks. I have copied the private key to `/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa` however, I still receive the permission denied error.

Comment: @Vincent. I have also tried generating fresh keys, updating github and /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa but still not luck.. Any ideas?

Comment: As I can see on http://help.github.com/linux-set-up-git/, you have to authenticate on github as the git user (not apache or root...).
You may investigate more... try 'su - apache' then 'ssh -T git@github.com'. If the key config is correct you might have a welcome message... If not, there still is a problem.

Comment: you may try using the **~/.ssh/config** file to tweak the ssh parameters of apache...

Answer (score 16):

Just posting the comment of @KitCarrau, under yvan's answer, that worked for me

`sudo -u apache ssh-keygen -t rsa`

for debian

`sudo -u www-data ssh-keygen -t rsa`

after this click Enter twice, to skip passphrase

also, it suggests to create the public/private keys in `/var/www/.ssh` directory, even if I had my www direcotry in `/home/my_user/www`, that is fine.

Answer (score 6):

The existing answers are either incomplete or insecure. If you put your `.ssh` directory into the home directory of the apache user (`/var/www`) then this will also most likely serve the contents of that directory and thus expose your ssh private key to the public web. To prevent this you'd have to configure apache *not* to serve the `.ssh` directory but none of the existing answers explains how to do this.

I'd also argue that it is still dangerous to have your `.ssh` directory be a subdirectory of your publicly served www-root because even if you add a rule to your apache config, upgrading the server or doing unrelated other configurations might override this rule without you noticing.

So here is an answer that puts the key elsewhere, where it is not served by apache by default. There is not even the need to ever become the `www-data` user as others are struggling with.

First, find out the home directory of our apache user, for example by looking into `/etc/passwd` and looking for the `www-data` user or however the apache user of your distribution is called. The home directory is likely `/var/www`.

Then run (replacing `/var/www` with the home directory of the apache user on your setup):

```
$ mkdir "$HOME/www-data.ssh"
$ ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -f "$HOME/www-data.ssh/id_rsa" -N ""
$ chown -R www-data:www-data "$HOME/www-data.ssh"
$ mkdir /var/www/.ssh
$ cat << END > /var/www/.ssh/config
> Host *
>     IdentityFile $HOME/www-data.ssh/id_rsa
> END
$ chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/.ssh
```

Now your `www-data` user will use the ssh key in `$HOME/www-data.ssh/id_rsa` for all its ssh connections and since your `$HOME` is probably different from `/var/www`, that directory will not be served. So even without adding any custom rules to apache, users will be able to see your `.ssh/config` but they will not be able to access the private key it points to. Nevertheless, your `www-data` user will know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

To add to @Vincent, if you have SELinux enabled, you'll have to set the context for the new .ssh folder.

On RHEL, add the following to this file: /etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.homedirs

```
/var/www/[^/]*/.+       system_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
/var/www/[^/]*/\.ssh(/.*)?      system_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0
```

And then run the command

```
# restorcon -Rv /var/www/
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue and there is one extra snag.  In order to ssh using the apache user you also need to edit the `/etc/passwd` file so that the directive for apache has a shell defined.

In my case I needed to change

```
apache:x:48:48:Apache:/var/www:/sbin/nologin
```

to

```
apache:x:48:48:Apache:/var/www:/bin/bash
```

Comment: This is potentially a big security hole. See [this serverfault question](http://serverfault.com/questions/540298/dangers-to-giving-apache-user-a-shell) for info on possible risks.

Comment: Yeah I gave this technique up a while back and opted to use a specific user not related to the apache user.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will work on redhat (I assume that is what you're running) however, I was able to su to www-data (the apache user for debian) by executing the following:

```
sudo su www-data
```

it actually worked *shrugs* go figure