# How to let apache to do ssh

Tags: php, ssh

I want to run some command from a remote server in my php using exec. Like this:

```
<? php
exec('ssh user@remote_server command');
?>
```

My account has access to ssh to that remote_server with public/private key but not apache. Note that I don't have root access to either of the machines. All the answers for [Generating SSH keys for 'apache' user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306990/generating-ssh-keys-for-apache-user) need root access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My recommendation: use [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).  eg.

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Web server process is owned by apache user not root .

1. Make sure  that apache user have password less login to remote server
2. SE linux should be disabled .  [Refer](http://wccandlinux.blogspot.in/2016/07/how-to-run-ssh-command-from-apache.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would try:

```
$identity_file = '/home/you/.ssh/id_rsa'; // <-- replace with actual priv key
exec('ssh -i ' . $identity_file . ' user@remote_server command');
```

and see if you can authenticate like that.  You will have to make sure that the identity file is readable by Apache.

The downside is now the Apache user can read your private key, which means any other site running as the Apache user can as well.  But even if you create a private key for the Apache user, the same is true.  For better security, see about running PHP as your specific user using suPHP or suExec.

Comment: Does not work. I need to make the identity file readable by apache. That means read by other (r+o). Apparently ssh does not like too open file mode!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad idea without root access. To make sure that Apache's user can see your private key, you'll have to make it world-readable: without root you can't `chown www-data:www-data`, so not only will Apache be able to see it, every user on the system will be able to. Because this is such a bad idea, OpenSSH won't allow it by default - it will refuse to run if your private key has unreasonably open file permissions.

I very strongly advise against doing this. If you really need to be able to have PHP run remote commands with an SSH key, you'll need someone with root access to set up something more secure, along the lines of your link.

A more secure alternative would be to write a PHP script on the target machine that takes an HTTP request containing a password that you define, executes a pre-defined command and returns the output. If this script is written securely and can only execute that one pre-defined command, all an attacker can do is run that same command as you - as long as the password for this script isn't the same as any of your own passwords. It needn't be exactly one command, and it can even take some arguments if you're careful: the important point is that you're not allowing a remote user to execute *arbitrary* commands on the target machine. If you're sure that the command you want to be able to run isn't potentially harmful, and your script doesn't contain coding errors allowing other commands to be run instead, then this isn't too bad an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Use SSH2.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php