# Verify a generated ssh-key to bitbucket on PHP script

Tags: php, git, ssh, bitbucket, webhooks

at the VPS ssh i put:

```
    admin@bpm3i:~$ ssh -vT git@bitbucket.org
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/admin/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/admin/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for bitbucket.org
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [131.103.20.168] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/admin/ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/admin/ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/admin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Remote: Forced command: conq username:workquality
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Remote: Forced command: conq username:workquality
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to bitbucket.org ([131.103.20.168]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
logged in as workquality.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 2752, received 2888 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 10079.8, received 10577.9
debug1: Exit status 0
```

And everything is fine

I make the same on a PHP CLI

```
    admin@bpm3i:~$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > echo exec('ssh -vT git@bitbucket.org');
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/admin/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/admin/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for bitbucket.org
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [131.103.20.167] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/admin/ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/admin/ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/admin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Remote: Forced command: conq username:workquality
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Remote: Forced command: conq username:workquality
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to bitbucket.org ([131.103.20.167]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 2752, received 2888 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 10205.4, received 10709.8
debug1: Exit status 0
You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
```

Looks good

and Then on a PHP CGI (apache):

```
<?php echo exec("ssh -vT git@bitbucket.org 2>&1");?>
```

And i get: Permission denied (publickey).

before that, i do:

I Loogin as 'admin' and generate ssh-key,

verify the user:

```
exec('whoami'); //admin
exec('echo ~'.$user); // /home/admin
```

I dont know what is wrong with it. OK on SSH, PHP-CLI, but on a webserver dont work, please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The apache user (`www-data`) doesn't have read access to the file which contains your user's ssh key, so it is not able to execute the command as linux is trying to execute it with user `www-data` with the CGI.

As for the `exec('whoami');` and `exec('echo ~'.$user);` commands, I think you are currently running them directly, try running them from within a PHP file and execute it via the webserver and you should definitely see a different user.

So, instead generate a ssh key for the apache user as mentioned [here (Check other answers as well)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7307050/1860929)

```
sudo -u apache ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

And add the public key with a readonly access on your bitbucket account.

Comment: I generate two ssh-keys, one for admin and other for www-data (apache user) and i put those in the bitbucket user SETTINGS and it works! Thanks for you reply

Answer (score 0):

This is because `ssh` will try find you ssh key by default in your home directory, in `admin`'s home directory.

When you execute it via apache, the script runs with a home directory far from admin. While you can pass the path to the key via commandline `ssh -i /path/to/key` it would be very insecure to give apache read access to the key of `admin`.

I would create a separate ssh key and use it only for bitbucket - read access. Then place it into a folder accessible by apache - but not browsable over the web.

You can now use the following `shell_exec()` call to test the connection:

```
<?php echo shell_exec("ssh -i /path/to/key -vT git@bitbucket.org 2>&1");?>
```