# Git deploy script fails, but SSH doesn't

Tags: git, github, ssh, version-control

A developer where I work has recently left, and I've been tasked with recycling all of our keys etc.

We use BitBucket for our source control and this particular developer has a "pull script" running on one of our servers that would pull anything from our development branch onto a test version of the site. After we removed his Atlassian account, it took the SSH key this deploy script used with it. I have since generated new keys, uploaded the public to my Atlassian account, and placed the private on the server, so far so good.

However his deploy script returns `Permission denied (publickey).`

When I try `$ ssh git@bitbucket.org` I get the following:

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
logged in as ChocolateDinosaur.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
Connection to bitbucket.org closed.
```

Which appears to work? (Forgive my ignorance if this is not the case)

The deploy script is as follows:

```
<?php
$commands = array(
    'echo $PWD',
    'whoami',
    'git pull',
    'git status',
    // 'git submodule sync',
    // 'git submodule update',
    // 'git submodule status',
);

$output = '';
foreach($commands AS $command){
    $tmp = shell_exec($command);
    $output .= "<span style=\"color: #6BE234;\">\$</span> <span style=\"color: #729FCF;\">{$command}\n</span>";
    $output .= htmlentities(trim($tmp)) . "\n";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>GIT DEPLOYMENT SCRIPT</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bold; padding: 0 10px;">

<pre>
<?=$output?>
</pre>

</body>
</html>
```

Source control is certainly not my forte and I see it as a necessary evil, I am assuming that the reason the script fails is that `git` on our server is either pointing to github rather than bitbucket, or still trying to use some of the previous developers credentials?

I have changed the `git config --global user.name` and `git config --global user.email` to try and combat this.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you testing the SSH command with the same user that run the PHP script?

Comment: Ah perhaps not! I imagine the script is being ran by www-data

Comment: So I think you need to enable the SSH for the www-data user

Comment: I think you are probably right, I'll have a crack at it now, if it works I'll let you know, if you post an answer I will give you the rep ofc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSH key need to be available to the user running your PHP script.

So take a look at [Generating SSH keys for 'apache' user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306990/generating-ssh-keys-for-apache-user) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7307059/439790).

BTW, `user.email` and `user.name` are for identification in commit data, authentication is done with SSH username and password, SSH key or HTTP authentication, with no relation to commit identification data.