# Gitlab webhooks not working due to shell script permission

Tags: php, git, laravel, gitlab, webhooks

Using laravel 5.6. I'm trying to set up a webhook on gitlab, to make a `git pull` on push events. I've created a post route, added controller and method, that launches a shell script:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

    class WebhookController extends Controller
    {
        public function handle(Request $request) {
            $root_path = base_path();
            $process = Process::fromShellCommandline('cd ' . $root_path . '; ./deploy.sh');
            $process->run(function($type, $buffer) {
                echo $buffer;
            });
        }
    }
```

Shell script itself contains just a one line:

```
#!/bin/sh

git pull
```

But in gitlab's request details, i see an error after a push:

```
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
```

I already `chmod 777 deploy.sh`, but i guess it tries to launch that script from different user? If i launch the script from my user, it just works (i'm using ssh key without a password).

**UPDATE**

I did `sudo chown -R $USER:www-data .` - now it doesn't show an error with permissions, except the one:

```
Could not create directory '/var/www/.ssh'.
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

It's trying to make a `git pull` using www-data user (i checked with whoami), so it doesn't have a right ssh key, how can i switch to my USERNAME?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSH keys are linked to users and your process inside your Laravel app most likely doesn't run as the user you've added your ssh key to. It probably runs as the `www-data` user.

Try and create an ssh key for your `www-data` user and use the key as a ["Deploy key"](https://www.deployhq.com/support/projects/updating-your-project-repository/uploading-your-public-key-to-gitlab-manually) on Gitlab. Try `sudo -u www-data ssh-keygen -t rsa` to create the ssh key. Also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306990/generating-ssh-keys-for-apache-user) question.

To answer you last question about switching to your username: that would not be a good idea. That way your application can run anything that your user would be able to run, which is not a good idea. Rather create a separate ssh key for that user and give it limited access to your repository (i.e. only read/pull access).

Comment: so it's better to generate ssh key for www-data user?

Comment: Yes, definitely. And then add that ssh key to your profile as a "Deploy key" rather than an ordinary access key.

Comment: it doesn't allow me to create .ssh folder - Could not create directory '/var/www/.ssh': Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

Anyone coming here lately, here is the guide:

- the script is run by user www-data when executed by Laravel Process. So, you first need to make sure to create ssh key for the user, www-data and add that to your gitlab account.

To create ssh key for www-data. follow below steps:

1. **sudo mkdir /var/www/.ssh** (as a root user, you create the directory)
2. **sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/.ssh**  (making .ssh directory read/write accessible to www-data user)
3. **sudo -u www-data ssh-keygen -t rsa** (creates rsa key)
   Now, just press enter. Don't add any password for the key.
   Next, you just need to copy the public key and add it to the gitlab account.

Happy Automation!