# How to run script file on remote server from another server using digital ocean servers through laravel app

Tags: laravel, symfony, security, networking, devops

I have a laravel app on my server when certain actions happen it runs a shell script file located on path `/home/user/myFile.sh`, I am using [Symfony component process](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#setting-environment-variables-for-processes) it's a response with an error `Host key verification failed`, and while I run using the terminal from the server it's work perfectly.
my question how can I pass this error to execute my file through my app.

This `myFile.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
ssh myuser@xx.xx.xx.xx "bash -s" <<'ENDSSH'
/home/user/another_file.sh $1 $2 $3
```

code inside laravel app:

```php
public function do()
{
  $process = new Process(['/home/user/myFile.sh'], null, ['param1', 'param2', 'param3']);
  $process->run();

  if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
  }

   return $process->getOutput();

}
```

`another_file.sh` on the remote server:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

p1= $1;
p2= $2;
p3= $3;

echo "script executed successfully";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is answered well over on AskUbuntu; https://askubuntu.com/a/323629/641754:

If you are running in certain remote/scripting situations where you lack interactive access to the prompt-to-add-hostkey, work around it like this:

```
$ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no myuser@xx.xx.xx.xx "bash -s" <<'ENDSSH'
```

Comment: thank you @James, I follow as you write I got `Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts Permission denied (publickey)`

Comment: still the same result!

Comment: I notice the error it's trying to access ssh key from a place where my app located
`Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/var/www/.ssh/known_hosts)`
when I used `ssh -v...`

Comment: I search to find who is execute the file when I run `new Process(['whoami'])` it's print `www-data` and finds the `www-data` has no permission to execute a file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213257/discussion-between-omda-and-james).

Comment: I solve my issue follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306990/generating-ssh-keys-for-apache-user